# SQL Trigger. How do I give the trigger the query "variables"?

Tags: azure

I need some help understanding how I handle the parameters the query pass onto the trigger. I've created a Trigger below which works for userrId 5. But lets say I try to delete a userr object with userrId = 4 in a query, which then start the Trigger, how do I place that userrId in the trigger.

I work in Visual Studio and use a Azure SQL DB.

```
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[userr]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
    AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM userHouses WHERE userrId = 5;
        DELETE FROM userr WHERE userrId = 5;
    END
```

Comment: Why you put mysql as tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you post another question?

Try this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger]
ON [dbo].[user]
AFTER DELETE
AS
DECLARE @user_id INT
SELECT @user_id = (SELECT userid FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM userHouse WHERE userid = @user_id;
END
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I deleted the old post I figured it was too clutered and the answer was not clear. Thanks for the answer, this is just what I needed and it works.